# css hover menu stops working after Update Panel renders elements

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, updatepanel

I am using `<ul> <li>` menu on master page. For menu hover I am using csshover.htc file.
I am `<updatepanel>` on my child pages, but when I click on any link or button inside update panel, my menu stops working. i.e hover does not work. What can be solution for this?

Comment: No I am using 'behavior: url("csshover3.htc");' to call htc file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got updated htc file from [here](http://naarvoren.nl/artikel/hover/csshover.htc), and my issue was resolved..

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-initialise your menu after your updatepanel has fired.  In order to do this you need to include something like the following at the bottom of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(CSSHover());‌
</script>
```

You will find the name of the function to be called at the top of your htc file - You will see something like this:

```
<public:attach event="ondocumentready" onevent="CSSHover()" />
```

The function that needs to be fired is the part in the onevent

Comment: Thanks, but now i get error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.
Parameter name: handler". What is causing this error?

Comment: Sorry try the CSSHover without the brackets `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(CSSHover);‌`

Comment: Yes.. that is what i tried initially, but I was getting error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Object' cannot be converted to type 'Function'.
Parameter name: handler", so i added brackets again

Comment: ah, I've never used an htc file so I don't know what order they are included.  Basically you need to make sure that csshover function has been defined before the endrequest manager is called